# Permissão para aplicativo android

Tags: android, android-eclipse, android-permission

Criei um aplicativo no eclipse para android, quando o instalo no celular ele não dá permissão, no caso foi um APK de radio web streaming, no aparelhos Samsung funciona 100%, mas nos motorola não funcionam.

Quando a gente instala um aplicativo tipo whatsapp na hora de instalar ele aparece algumas perguntas pedindo permissão.
Então lá vem a minha pergunta, como colocar esse código em meu APK para quando abrir ele fazer as mesmas perguntas antes de começar a usar ele?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tens de assinar o APK da app.
Ve este link: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html
Também podes seguir esta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4853025/2486919

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que ainda não criou permissões, deve ir ao `AndroidMainfest.xml` e definir as permissões que pretende:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.app.myapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Para saber que permissões deve usar consulte esta página:
[Lista de permissões - Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html?hl=pt-br)

---

> A partir do Android 6.0 (nível de API 23), os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados.

Talvez este seja o caso do seu motorola, por isso aconselho dar uma vista de olhos numa outra página: [Solicitação de permissões em tempo de execução](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

---

Espero que ajude.